# Loop through list of URLs and save content to text file

Tags: php

I am trying to loop through a list of URLs and save content from a div tag to a text file.

```
<?php
$file = 'content.txt';
$i = 406;
for($i; $i <= 1410; $i++) {
    $url = 'http://example.com/chapter/chapter-'.$i;
    $content = file_get_contents($url);

    $start_tag = explode( '<div class="textdiv">' , $content );
    $end_tag = explode("</div>" , $start_tag[1] );
    $result_text = $second_step[0];
    echo $result_text; 
    $result = file_put_contents($file,  $result_text);
}
?>
```

The first problem is that there are multiple occurrences of the div tag with that class and I want to get every div with that class and the current code just outputs first occurrence.

[EDIT] 

Thanks to The Alpha's help for pointing me to right direction, This worked for me:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$i = 399;
$file = 'content.txt';

for($i; $i < 1400; $i++){
$url = 'http://example.com/chapter/chapter-'.$i;
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach ($html->find('div.textdiv') as $div) {
    echo $div . '<br />';
   $result = file_put_contents($file,  $div );
}
echo '<hr><br /><h1>Chapter '. $i .'</h1><br /><hr>';
}
?>
```

One Issue was it takes very very long time for the script to run.

Comment: Just try [this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm). Also, some [related answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A741747+simple+html+dom).

Comment: Try using DOMDocument and DOMXPath.

Comment: Hi Thanks simple file_get_html did the trick for me. I am editing my question to indicate what worked.

Comment: One Issue was it takes very very long time for the script to run.